# BiocCheck function additional parameters usage fail [R]

Tags: r, package, bioconductor

I am trying to check a package for compliance with Bioconductor package guidelines with `BiocCheck` function from [`BiocCheck` package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/BiocCheck.html). I have problem with vignettes compilation so I was about to skip that part of check and I wanted to pass further arguments to this function. I was following instructions from manual of `BiocCheck` function where there is a sentence

> ...
>   Run usage() to see the available options. When running BiocCheck interactively, options can be passed like so: BiocCheck(package, `no-check-vignettes`=TRUE)

but I failed with such an error:

**Anyone knows how to fix this?**

```
> usage()
Usage: R CMD BiocCheck [options] package


Options:
    --no-check-vignettes
        disable vignette checks

    --new-package
        enable checks specific to new packages

    --no-check-bioc-views
        disable biocViews-specific checks (for non-BioC packages)

    -h, --help
        Show this help message and exit


When running interactively, options can be passed like so:
BiocCheck(package, `no-check-vignettes`=TRUE)
> BiocCheck(package = getwd(), `no-check-vignettes`=TRUE)
* This is BiocCheck, version 1.4.0.
* BiocCheck is a work in progress. Output and severity of issues
  may change.
* Installing package...
    * CONSIDER: Clarifying how objects ‘., ., ., .’ (used in
      availableDates, read.mutations, read.rnaseq,
      whichDateToUse) were initialized. Maybe they are part of a
      data set loaded with data(), or perhaps part of an object
      referenced in with() or within().
Error in dots[["no-check-vignettes"]] : subscript out of bounds
> BiocCheck(package = getwd(), "no-check-vignettes"=TRUE)
* This is BiocCheck, version 1.4.0.
* BiocCheck is a work in progress. Output and severity of issues
  may change.
* Installing package...
    * CONSIDER: Clarifying how objects ‘., ., ., .’ (used in
      availableDates, read.mutations, read.rnaseq,
      whichDateToUse) were initialized. Maybe they are part of a
      data set loaded with data(), or perhaps part of an object
      referenced in with() or within().
Error in dots[["no-check-vignettes"]] : subscript out of bounds
```

**My session info is:**

```
> session_info()
Session info -----------------------------------------------------------------------
 setting  value                       
 version  R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)
 system   x86_64, mingw32             
 ui       RStudio (0.99.441)          
 language (EN)                        
 collate  Polish_Poland.1250          
 tz       Europe/Warsaw               

Packages ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 package        * version  date       source                                   
 assertthat       0.1      2013-12-06 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 Biobase          2.28.0   2015-04-17 Bioconductor                             
 BiocCheck      * 1.4.0    2015-04-17 Bioconductor                             
 BiocGenerics     0.14.0   2015-04-17 Bioconductor                             
 BiocInstaller  * 1.18.4   2015-07-22 Bioconductor                             
 biocViews        1.36.2   2015-06-19 Bioconductor                             
 bitops           1.0-6    2013-08-17 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 chron            2.3-47   2015-06-24 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 codetools        0.2-14   2015-07-15 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 curl             0.9.1    2015-07-04 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 data.table     * 1.9.4    2014-10-02 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 devtools       * 1.8.0    2015-05-09 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 digest           0.6.8    2014-12-31 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 getopt           1.20.0   2013-08-30 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 git2r            0.10.1   2015-05-07 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 graph            1.46.0   2015-04-17 Bioconductor                             
 htmltools        0.2.6    2014-09-08 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 httr             1.0.0    2015-06-25 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 knitr            1.10.5   2015-05-06 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 knitrBootstrap   1.0.0    2015-08-05 Github (jimhester/knitrBootstrap@cdaa4a9)
 magrittr         1.5      2014-11-22 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 markdown         0.7.7    2015-04-22 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 memoise          0.2.1    2014-04-22 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 optparse         1.3.0    2014-12-11 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 plyr             1.8.3    2015-06-12 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 R6               2.1.0    2015-07-04 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 RBGL             1.44.0   2015-04-17 Bioconductor                             
 Rcpp             0.12.0   2015-07-25 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 RCurl            1.95-4.7 2015-06-30 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 reshape2         1.4.1    2014-12-06 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 rmarkdown        0.7.3    2015-08-05 Github (rstudio/rmarkdown@88afb8d)       
 RTCGA          * 0.99.0   2015-08-05 Bioconductor (R 3.2.1)                   
 RUnit            0.4.28   2015-01-06 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 rversions        1.0.2    2015-07-13 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 rvest          * 0.2.0    2015-01-01 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 stringi          0.5-5    2015-06-29 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 stringr          1.0.0    2015-04-30 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 XML              3.98-1.3 2015-06-30 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 xml2             0.1.1    2015-06-02 CRAN (R 3.2.1)                           
 yaml             2.1.13   2014-06-12 CRAN (R 3.2.1)
```

Comment: Do you get the same thing if you run it from the command line as `R CMD BiocCheck yourpackage`

Comment: `can't find command` - by the way I am asking about additional parameter to function, not about running it from command line

Comment: Yeah I understand that but it can help diagnose the issue

Comment: I am using windows, so `cmd` is rather poor

Comment: Using BiocCheck implies you are developing a Bioconductor package. That means you should be asking on the bioc-devel mailing list (https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/bioc-devel).

Comment: @DanTenenbaum this takes to much time: 'Your subscription request has been received, and will soon be acted upon. Depending on the configuration of this mailing list, your subscription request may have to be first confirmed by you via email, or approved by the list moderator. If confirmation is required, you will soon get a confirmation email which contains further instructions.'

Comment: @MarcinKosinski I tried it and it took less than a minute to receive the email and click the link in it, then click a link on the resulting page. Then I was subscribed. It takes a lot less time than waiting for someone who knows the answer to come along on SO. Have you looked in your spam folder for the email? In any case, you must be subscribed before your package will be accepted. bioc-devel is the place where the most interested parties will benefit from the discussion. That said I will look at RTCGA and try and figure out what is going on.

Comment: This issue is fixed in BiocCheck 1.5.7 in devel. It will be available via biocLite() on Friday around noon Seattle time, or you can get it now via svn or github. If you resubmit your package to the tracker (with the `VignetteBuilder: knitr` line added to the DESCRIPTION file) the updated BiocCheck will run against it.

Comment: Thanks for many help @DanTenenbaum! It's a good idea to attend the bioc-devel mailing list. You can post your advice with `VignetteBuilder: knitr` as an answer :)

Comment: Also I had to add knitr to `Depends`

Comment: knitr should be in `Suggests`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Dan suggested, one should add `VignetteBuilder: knitr` and `Suggests: knitr`